# Limiting the max number of items being searched

Tags: json, reactjs

So the thing I want to achieve is this. I want to display max of 10 items per search, so whenever I type a word it only displays 10 items. Right now it is displaying a nice amount. I have tried something am I on the right path

```
import React,{useState, useEffect, useRef, useContext}from 'react'
import {FaSearch} from 'react-icons/fa'
import { 
    Link, useHistory
  } from "react-router-dom";
import { BookContext } from '../../context/books';
import SearchBooks from './SearchBooks';

const Search = () => {

  const {data}= useContext(BookContext)
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = React.useState('');
  const history= useHistory()
  const ref=useRef()
  function filterBooks(book) {
    console.log(book);
    if(!searchValue.length ) return book.bookName < 10
    if (!searchValue.length  ) return false;
    return book.bookName?.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase());
  }  

    return (
        <div className='search__cont' ref={ref}>   
           <SearchBooks searchValue={searchValue} setSearchValue={setSearchValue }/>          
           {Object.keys(data)
             .map((key) => data[key])
             .reduce((acc, curr) => acc.concat(curr), [])
             .filter(filterBooks)
             .map((book) => {          
             return (
             <>       
              <div  className='search__books'
                onClick={() => {
                  history.push("/book/id", { book }); setSearchValue('')
                }}
               >            
                {" "}
                {book.bookName}{" "}
              </div>            
            </>
          );
        })}
           </div>
    )
}

export default Search
```